# sorting an array with unique scenario

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with sorting arrays in javascript:

My original array:

```
let orginalArray = ["Apple","apple","Acrobat","APPLE","Account","account","Banana","banana","carrot","Carrot",1,2,"BANANA","BB","AA"];
```

Looking for an output like this:

```
sortedArray = ["AA","APPLE","Account","Acrobat","Apple","account","apple","BANANA","BB","Banana","banana","Carrot","carrot",1,2];
```

This is what I tried:

```
let sortedArray = orginalArray; 
sortedArray.sort((a, b) => a[keyname].toString().localeCompare(b[keyname].toString(),'en', { caseFirst: 'upper' }));
```

expecting,

```
sortedArray = ["Account","Acrobat","Apple","account","apple","Banana","banana","Carrot","carrot",1,2];
```

Comment: Please explain the desired outcome in text, e.g. something like "I want capitalised words to appear first" as well as any other conditions. Right now, it's not clear how you get from the input to the output.

Comment: Also, never ask for things "like" something: be exact. So to help with that, please remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: btw `let sortedArray = orginalArray;` won't copy the array, but just make another reference to `originalArray` and if you call `sortedArray.sort(...)` this will also update `originalArray` (because they are both pointing to the same array)

Answer (score 1):

Some crazy almost one-liner could be the following:

```js
let originalArray= [10,"Apple",2,1,2,"apple","Acrobat","Account","account","Banana","banana","carrot","Carrot", 0];

const compareUpper = Intl.Collator('en', {caseFirst: 'upper'}).compare;
const compare = Intl.Collator('en').compare;

const r = originalArray.slice().sort((a, b, [ta] = typeof a, [tb] = typeof b, na = ta === 'n') => 
  ta === tb ? na ? a - b : compareUpper(a[0], b[0]) || compare(a, b) : na * 2 - 1
);

console.log(...r);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will

- sort numbers in ascending order after strings
- all strings that start with an uppercase letter before all strings that start with the same letter in lowercase

**Edit**

Adjusted for multiple uppercase letters in the same word

```js
let originalArray = ["Apple","apple","Acrobat","APPLE","Account","account","Banana","banana","carrot","Carrot",1,2,"BANANA","BB","AA", "AAA", "AA"];

function lexCompare(a,b) {
  let minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
  //compare the letters of the words separately
  //up to the length of the shorter word
  for (let i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    //if the current letter in the words is equal, continue to next letter
    if (a[i] === b[i]) continue;
    //else return the difference    
    return a[i].localeCompare(b[i], "en", { caseFirst: 'upper' });
  }
  //if no difference found yet, the shorter of the two words has to be sorted first
  return a.length - b.length;
}

let sortedArray = originalArray.slice().sort((a,b) => {
  if (typeof a === typeof b) {
    //if a and b have the same type (ie both are number or string)
    return typeof a === "number"
      ? a - b  //both are numbers, sort them ascending
      : lexCompare(a,b)  //use the sorting function for strings defined above
  } else {
    return typeof a === "number"
      ? 1 // a is a number, b is a string so b has to be sorted before a
      : -1 // b is a number, a is a string so a has to be sorted before b
  }
})

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Not working when repeated Capital letters come , like AAple BBana